# How to call a template function to test in another file to test it with CppUnit

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cppunit

I am creating a simple MergeSort algorithm with array type(`array<int,N>`).
The function `mergeSortByMyself` is written with templates.
I want to test it with CppUnit, but when I run the code, it shows:
[image: Failed Output]

My `.h` files is "mergeModel.h", which contains:

```
#pragma once
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

template<typename Iterator>
void print(Iterator list);

template<size_t M, size_t P>
array<int,M+P> merge(array<int,M>& arr1, array<int,P>& arr2);

template<size_t N>
array<int,N> mergeSortByMyself(array<int,N>& list);
```

Then, I have include "mergeModel.h" in "MergeSortByMyself.cpp", this file contains:

```
#include "mergeSortModel.h"

template<typename Iterator>
void print(Iterator list){
    for(auto item: list ){
        cout << item << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
template<size_t M, size_t P>
array<int,M+P> merge(array<int,M>& arr1, array<int,P>& arr2){
    cout << "Merge starts here......."<<endl;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    array<int,arr1.size()+arr2.size()> joined;
    cout << "a1: " << arr1.size() << " a2: "<< arr2.size() << " a3: "<<joined.size()<< endl;
    for(k = 0; k < joined.size(); k++){
        if(i < arr1.size() && j < arr2.size() && arr1[i] < arr2[j]){
            joined[k] = arr1[i];
            i++;
        }else if( i < arr1.size() && j < arr2.size() &&  arr1[i] > arr2[j]){
            joined[k] = arr2[j];
            j++;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if(i == arr1.size()){
        for(; k < joined.size();k++  ){
            // cout << "j= "<<j << " k= "<<k<< endl;
            joined[k] = arr2[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    if(j == arr2.size()){
        for(; k < joined.size(); k++){
            joined[k] = arr1[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    cout << "joined ";
    print(joined);  
    return joined;
}

//array<int,N>
template<size_t N>
array<int,N> mergeSortByMyself(array<int,N>& list){
    if(list.size() <= 1){
        return list;
    }
    const int firstPart = (const int)list.size()/2;
    array<int, firstPart> leftArr;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < firstPart; i++){
        leftArr[i] = list[i];
    }
    array<int,list.size() - firstPart> rightArr;
    for(i=firstPart; i < list.size(); i++){
        rightArr[i-firstPart] = list[i];
    }
    print(list);
    print(leftArr);
    print(rightArr);

    leftArr = mergeSortByMyself(leftArr);
    rightArr = mergeSortByMyself(rightArr);

    array<int,list.size()> joined;
    if(leftArr[leftArr.size() -1] > rightArr[0]){
        joined = merge(leftArr,rightArr);
    }else{
        int y = 0;
        for(int g = 0; g < joined.size(); g++){
            if(y < leftArr.size()){
                joined[g] = leftArr[y];
            }else{
                joined[g] = rightArr[y-leftArr.size()];
            }
            y++;
        }
    }
    return joined;
}
```

Apparently, the code works well in the main() function:

```
int main(){
    array<int,3> arr = {3,2,1};
    array<int,3> sorted = mergeSortByMyself(arr);
    print(sorted);
}
```

But when I try to run "mergeSortByMyself()" function using CppUnit. it shows a that error:
[image: Failed Output]
The file "testing.cpp" use CppUnit and "mergeModel.h":

```
//testing.cpp
#include "mergeSortModel.h"
#include <cppunit/TestRunner.h>
#include <cppunit/TestResult.h>
#include <cppunit/TestResultCollector.h>
#include <cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h>
#include <cppunit/BriefTestProgressListener.h>
#include <cppunit/extensions/TestFactoryRegistry.h>
// #define N 100;

template<typename Iterator>
void print(Iterator list){
    for(auto item: list){
        cout << item << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
template<typename Iterator>
string toStr(Iterator list){
    string str="";
    for(auto item: list){
        str += to_string(item);
    }
    return str;
}

class Test : public CPPUNIT_NS::TestCase
{
  CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(Test);
  CPPUNIT_TEST(testMergeSort);
  CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();

public:
  void setUp(void) {}
  void tearDown(void) {} 

protected:
    void testMergeSort(void){
        const size_t n = 12;
        array<int,n> tosort;
        array<int,n> tosort_test;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            tosort[i] = rand()%100;
            tosort_test[i] = tosort[i];
        }

        // copy(tosort.begin(), tosort.end(), tosort_test);
        sort(tosort.begin(),tosort.end());

        array<int,n> sorted = mergeSortByMyself<tosort_test.size()>(tosort_test);        

        CPPUNIT_ASSERT(toStr(tosort)==toStr(tosort_test));
        // print(tosort);

    }
};

CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION(Test);

int main( int ac, char **av )
{
    srand(time(0));
 
    CPPUNIT_NS::TestResult controller;

    CPPUNIT_NS::TestResultCollector result;
    controller.addListener( &result );        

    CPPUNIT_NS::BriefTestProgressListener progress;
    controller.addListener( &progress );      

    CPPUNIT_NS::TestRunner runner;
    runner.addTest( CPPUNIT_NS::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry().makeTest());
    runner.run( controller );

    return result.wasSuccessful() ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Command to run the code that I used: `g++ mergeSortByMyself.cpp testing.cpp -lcppunit -o test`

Comment: Either, all templated code should be in header file or you need to instantiate all template specializations which you will use.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, you were right [@sklott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11680056/sklott).
There are only two ways that a compiler knows about a specific template function:

1. First: Pass all your template definitions(your code implementation) in the ".h" file.
2. Second: Write a specific implementation in the ".cpp" file.

A useful link what helped to me is [this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#separate-template-class-defn-from-decl)

I think the second way is not feasible for my template function because the `mergeSortByMySelf()` function is constantly changing the template parameter "**size_t N**":

```
template<size_t N>
array<int,N> mergeSortByMyself(array<int,N>& list)
```

So I decided to do the first method, which is easier, but in isocpp.org, in the link presented before, it says:

> The first solution is to physically move the definition of the
> template functions into the .h file, even if they are not inline
> functions. This solution may (or may not!) cause significant code
> bloat, meaning your executable size may increase dramatically (or, if
> your compiler is smart enough, may not; try it and see).

Nevertheless, I did it.
This is "mergeSortModel.h":

```
#pragma once
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

template<typename Iterator>
void print(Iterator list);

template<size_t M, size_t P>
array<int,M+P> merge(array<int,M>& arr1, array<int,P>& arr2);

template<size_t N>
array<int,N> mergeSortByMyself(array<int,N>& list);

//-------------------------DEFINITIONS of TEMPLATES
template<typename Iterator>
void print(Iterator list){
    for(auto item: list ){
        cout << item << " ";
    }
    // cout << "\n**********"<<endl;
    cout <<endl;
}
template<size_t M, size_t P>
array<int,M+P> merge(array<int,M>& arr1, array<int,P>& arr2){
    // cout << "Merge starts here......."<<endl;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    array<int,arr1.size()+arr2.size()> joined;
    // cout << "a1: " << arr1.size() << " a2: "<< arr2.size() << " a3: "<<joined.size()<< endl;

    // cout << "partA: ";
    // print(arr1);
    // cout << "\n";
    // cout << "partB: ";
    // print(arr2);
    // cout << "\n";
    
    for(k = 0; k < joined.size(); k++){
        if(i < arr1.size() && j < arr2.size() && arr1[i] < arr2[j]){
            joined[k] = arr1[i];
            i++;
        }else if( i < arr1.size() && j < arr2.size() &&  arr1[i] >= arr2[j]){
            //arr1[i] >= arr2[j] This is important, 
            //there was an error with "arr1[i] > arr2[j]"
            joined[k] = arr2[j];
            j++;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if(i == arr1.size()){
        for(; k < joined.size();k++  ){
            // // cout << "j= "<<j << " k= "<<k<< endl;
            joined[k] = arr2[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    if(j == arr2.size()){
        for(; k < joined.size(); k++){
            joined[k] = arr1[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    // cout << "joined ";
    // print(joined);  
    return joined;
}

//array<int,N>
template<size_t N>
array<int,N> mergeSortByMyself(array<int,N>& list){
    if(list.size() <= 1){
        return list;
    }
    const int firstPart = (const int)list.size()/2;
    array<int, firstPart> leftArr;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < firstPart; i++){
        leftArr[i] = list[i];
    }
    array<int,list.size() - firstPart> rightArr;
    for(i=firstPart; i < list.size(); i++){
        rightArr[i-firstPart] = list[i];
    }
    // cout << "\nCall starts here.....................\n";
    // print(list);
    // print(leftArr);
    // print(rightArr);
    // cout << "\nCall ends here.....................\n";

    leftArr = mergeSortByMyself(leftArr);
    rightArr = mergeSortByMyself(rightArr);

    array<int,list.size()> joined;
    if(leftArr[leftArr.size() -1] > rightArr[0]){
        joined = merge(leftArr,rightArr);
    }else{
        int y = 0;
        for(int g = 0; g < joined.size(); g++){
            if(y < leftArr.size()){
                joined[g] = leftArr[y];
            }else{
                joined[g] = rightArr[y-leftArr.size()];
            }
            y++;
        }
    }
    return joined;
}
```

And this is the UnitTest with CppUnit:

```
//testing.cpp
#include "mergeSortModel.h"
#include <cppunit/TestRunner.h>
#include <cppunit/TestResult.h>
#include <cppunit/TestResultCollector.h>
#include <cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h>
#include <cppunit/BriefTestProgressListener.h>
#include <cppunit/extensions/TestFactoryRegistry.h>
// #define N 100;

// template<typename Iterator>
// void print(Iterator list){
//     for(auto item: list){
//         cout << item << " ";
//     }
//     cout << endl;
// }
template<typename Iterator>
string toStr(Iterator list){
    string str="";
    for(auto item: list){
        str += to_string(item)+" ";
    }
    cout <<"\n|"<<str<<"|\n";
    return str;
}
template<size_t M>
bool test_arrays(array<int,M> a, array<int,M> b){
    if(a.size() != b.size()) 
        return false;

    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i){
        if(!(a[i] == b[i])) 
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
class Test : public CPPUNIT_NS::TestCase
{
  CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(Test);
  CPPUNIT_TEST(testMergeSort);
  CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();

public:
  void setUp(void) {}
  void tearDown(void) {} 

protected:
    void testMergeSort(void){
        const size_t n = 73;
        array<int,n> tosort;
        array<int,n> tosort_test;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            tosort[i] = rand()%100;
            tosort_test[i] = tosort[i];
        }
        toStr(tosort);
        toStr(tosort_test);
        // copy(tosort.begin(), tosort.end(), tosort_test);
        sort(tosort.begin(),tosort.end());
        array<int,n> sorted = mergeSortByMyself<tosort_test.size()>(tosort_test);
        cout << "------------RESULTS--------------\n";
        toStr(tosort);
        toStr(sorted);
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT(test_arrays<n>(tosort,sorted));

        // print(tosort);
        // print(sorted);
    }
};


CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION(Test);

int main( int ac, char **av )
{
    srand(time(0));
 
    CPPUNIT_NS::TestResult controller;

    CPPUNIT_NS::TestResultCollector result;
    controller.addListener( &result );        

    CPPUNIT_NS::BriefTestProgressListener progress;
    controller.addListener( &progress );      

    CPPUNIT_NS::TestRunner runner;
    runner.addTest( CPPUNIT_NS::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry().makeTest());
    runner.run( controller );

    return result.wasSuccessful() ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Command to run it: `g++ testing.cpp -lcppunit -o test`

Size of "test" is:

```
122792 Jan 25 22:55 test
```